# How do I HTTP Trigger a Google Cloud Function in Angular?

Tags: rest, angular, firebase, email, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to setup a REST API via Google Cloud Functions to send emails that can be consumed by my Angular app which is hosted by Firebase. My problem is that I cannot get my Angular code to trigger my google cloud function. Can anyone explain what is going wrong?

---

#### Server-Side Google Cloud Function Code

I have this Google Cloud function within `functions/index.js`:

```js
// index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const sg = require('sendgrid')(
  process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY || '<my-api-key-placed-here>'
);

exports.sendmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  sendMail(req.body);
  res.send("Mail Successfully Sent!");
})


function sendMail(formData) {
  const mailRequest = sg.emptyRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v3/mail/send',
    body: {
      personalizations: [{
        to: [{ email: 'my.email@gmail.com' }],
        subject: 'Greenwich Test'
      }],
      from: { email: 'noreply@email-app.firebaseapp.com' },
      content: [{
        type: 'text/plain',
        value: 'Hello Joe! Can you hear me! Is the line still getting through?'
      }]
    }
  });

  sg.API(mailRequest, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Mail not sent; see error message below.');
    } else {
      console.log('Mail sent successfully!');
    }
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Which I can successfully trigger in my browser by pasting this in the address bar:

`https://us-central1-email-app.cloudfunctions.net/sendmail`

I get an email within five minutes when entering this in the browser. However, I cannot get Angular to trigger this function.

---

#### Client-Side Angular Code

Below is my client-side code. `contact-form.service.ts` contains the submit button's function.

```html
<!-- contact-form.component.html -->
<form [formGroup]="formService.contactForm" (ngSubmit)="formService.onSubmitForm()">

  <input type="text" formControlName="userFirstName">
  <label class="first-name-footer">First Name</label>

  <input type="text" formControlName="userLastName">
  <label class="last-name-footer">Last Name</label>

  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
```

```js
// contact-form.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ContactFormService } from './contact-form.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-content.component.css'],
  providers: [ContactFormService]
})
export class ContactFormComponent {

  constructor(public formService: ContactFormService) {
    formService.buildForm();
  }

}
```

```js
// contact-form.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ContactFormService {

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public http: Http) { }

  contactForm: FormGroup;
  formSubmitted: boolean = false;
  mailUrl = "https://us-central1-email-app.cloudfunctions.net/sendmail";


  buildForm() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userFirstName: this.formBuilder.control(null, Validators.required),
      userLastName: this.formBuilder.control(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  onSubmitForm() {
    console.log(this.contactForm.value);
    this.formSubmitted = true;
    this.http.post(this.mailUrl, this.contactForm.value);
    this.contactForm.reset();
  }
}
```

When I click the submit button, my Google Cloud function fails to trigger, but `this.contactForm.value` correctly display in the console.

So in conclusion: How do I get my Angular submit button to trigger my google cloud function? The function successfully fires when I use the url in my browser, but I cannot get my Angular app to trigger that same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe for any http requests else your call will not be raised

```
onSubmitForm() {
    console.log(this.contactForm.value);
    this.formSubmitted = true;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.http.post(this.mailUrl, this.contactForm.value).subscribe();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.contactForm.reset();
  }
```